Print Multiple File Paths to File Without Double Quote-Wrapping?
I am attempting to use ffmpeg to concatenate multiple video files together, using an example of saving all files supplied to a file from here (under Automatically generating the input file) with a for loop. The file is successfully created where I want it to be, but upon execution of the command the output  states: Unsafe file name '"C:\Users\Mr. Mendelli\Desktop\Track 1.mp4"'. The contents of my file index are as follows within the file:
file '"C:\Users\Mr. Mendelli\Desktop\Track 1.mp4"'
file '"C:\Users\Mr. Mendelli\Desktop\Track 2.mp4"'

I am under the impression that the issue is that the file paths are being wrapped in double quotes, but I can't figure out how to get rid of them within the for loop example I am using I have tried their example with and without the single quote-wrapping %%i to no avail:
...
(
    for %%i in (
    %*
) do @echo file '%%i') > "%temp%\FileIndex"
...

Additionally, unless there is an alternate wildcard, I am using %* as the use of this script may be used for two or more files, it is not guaranteed I will always only merge two.
Update:
I have determined the issue, though I still can't resolve it within my code:

File paths must only be single quote wrapped.
Path delimiters must be forward slashes, not backslashes even on Windows.

How would I ensure single quotes and forward slashes are printed to FileIndex within my batch script?

I answered below about the unsafe file thing and how it can be dealt with. But TBH something doesn't make sense with your example for loop. How exactly is the index file with paths like file '"C:\Users\Mr. Mendelli\Desktop\Track 1.mp4"' generated?

Using example 3 under 'Automatically generating the input file' from here @YisroelTech:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate
I have also tried making various edits to the example code with mixed results but none that I am looking for.

I tried all examples there and none of them give an output like this with double-quotes...

See here https://streamable.com/8ku7sw

I do not think it has to do with the double quotes, it has to do with the full file paths (and not relative file names).
See https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options:

A file path is considered safe if it does not contain a protocol specification and is relative

You can simply ignore the FFmpeg "Safety check" by adding -safe 0 to the FFmpeg command. This is widely used and should generally not cause any issues.

I am already using the -safe 0 switch and I have verified it is both the double quotes and backslashes on Windows. Using a file I wrote manually containing single quotes and forward slashes resolved the issue but I am still unable to manage doing this within my code.

I had inadvertently answered my own question earlier in my code that I overlooked with a for loop that lists all files supplied to the script and it is as simple as adding one character to an existing variable. Using %%~i was the key as it does not include double quotes in the paths to files processed within the loop.
...
(
    for %%i in (
    %*
) do @echo file '%%~i') > "%temp%\FileIndex"
...

